# Append property from two arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop

In JavaScript, I have two arrays - `arr1`, `arr2`

`arr1` is an array of objects as shown below -

```
[
   { user: {id: 1, name: "name1", role: "A"} },
   { user: {id: 2, name: "name2", role: "B"} },
   { user: {id: 3, name: "name3", role: "A"} }
]
```

`arr2` is also an array of objects :

```
[
   { id: 2, username: "brad", ... },
   { id: 1, username: "colly", ... },
   { id: 3, username: "sophie", ... }
]
```

Now, what I want to get an output `arr1` like this -

```
[
   { user: {id: 1, name: "name1", role: "A", username: "colly"} },
   { user: {id: 2, name: "name2", role: "B", username: "brad"} },
   { user: {id: 3, name: "name3", role: "A", username: "sophie"} }
]
```

Basically, if `arr1[0].user.id = arr2[1].id` then add the `username` property from `arr2` to that `user` with the `id`. Same across the entire array, and then finally return the original array `arr1` with `username` appended to each respective `user` object.

Hope you understand what I tried to explain. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way that only iterates each array once is to map arr2 to an object or Map with `id` as keys then loop over arr1 and look each id up to get the username.

An object or Map lookup is an o(1) operation whereas methods like find() require numerous iterations of arr2

```js
const arr1=[{user:{id:1,name:"name1",role:"A"}},{user:{id:2,name:"name2",role:"B"}},{user:{id:3,name:"name3",role:"A"}}],
  arr2=[{id:2,username:"brad"},{id:1,username:"colly"},{id:3,username:"sophie"}];

const arr2Names = new Map(arr2.map(e => [e.id, e.username]));

arr1.forEach(({user}) => user.username = arr2Names.get(user.id))

console.log(arr1)
```

Comment: Great answer, I knew there was a way to do it without looping through both  arrays, just couldn't think of it that moment.

Comment: @sschwei1, ```const arr2Names = new Map(arr2.map(e => [e.id, e.username]));``` I think you already loop arr2 with ```arr2.map()``` here....Not to loop two array is unavoidable so far I know...

Comment: @ikhvjs He is looping once arr1, but he avoids to loop arr2 multiple times (nested loop).

Comment: @ikhvjs i am sorry, i was thinking in o-notations, 2n is shortened to n, so i said `loop through 1 array`, what i actually ment, was that a nested loop is avoided and complexity is reduced from n² -> n

Comment: @sschwei1, No worries. I get your point now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` and `find` in your case.

```js
const arr1 = [
  { user: { id: 1, name: "name1", role: "A" } },
  { user: { id: 2, name: "name2", role: "B" } },
  { user: { id: 3, name: "name3", role: "A" } },
];

const arr2 = [
  { id: 2, username: "brad" },
  { id: 1, username: "colly" },
  { id: 3, username: "sophie" },
];

const output = arr1.map(el => ({
  user: { ...el.user, username: arr2.find(x => x.id === el.user.id).username },
}));

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
const arr1 = [
  { user: {id: 1, name: "name1", role: "A"} },
  { user: {id: 2, name: "name2", role: "B"} },
  { user: {id: 3, name: "name3", role: "A"} }
];

const arr2 = [
  { id: 2, username: "brad", ... },
  { id: 1, username: "colly", ... },
  { id: 3, username: "sophie", ... }
]

mergedArray = arr1.map(e => {
  return {
    user: {
      ...e.user,
      username: arr2.find(x => x.id === e.user.id).username
    }
  }
})
```

In case you want to merge more values than just the username, you can save the value found in arr2 in a variable:

```
mergedArray = arr1.map(e => {
  const match = arr2.find(x => x.id === e.user.id);
  return {
    user: {
      ...e.user,
      username: match.username,
      someOtherValue: match.someOtherValue
    }
  }
})
```

If it is not certain, that objects in arr2, contain a username, you will get an error when accessing the username in the function, `username: match?.username ?? 'fallbackValue'` will prevent the error and return a default value in case, if no default value is needed, you can leave the `?? '...'` part

Answer (score 0):

Given your two arrays, you will need to do this:

```
// loop through all the elements in arr1    
const result = arr1.map(element => {
      // Search the element by ID in arr2 (You need to loop every time, probably not the better solution.
      // Maybe better with a Map
      const elInArr2Found = arr2.find(arr2Element => arr2Element.id === element.user.id);
      // If the element is found, set the property "username" to the element
      // If the element is not found, leave it as is
      if (elInArr2Found !== undefined) {
        element.user.username = elInArr2Found.username;
      }
      // return the element
      return element;
    })
```

**result** will have all your elements with the username set.

Check the [Map documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to this avoid nested loop.