# How to add book author by comparing book id from two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, loops, object

```
var books = [
  {id: 1, title: "Javascript"},
  {id: 2, title: "PHP"},
  {id: 3, title: "Dart"},
  {id: 4, title: "C++"}
]
var authors = [
  {book_id: 1, user: {id: 1, name: "John Doe"}},
  {book_id: 3, user: {id: 4, name: "Alex Rio"}},
  {book_id: 4, user: {id: 42, name: "Paul Radmond"}}
]

for(var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
  let bookAuthor = authors.find(author => {
    return author.book_id === books[i].id
  })

  console.log(bookAuthor.user)
  
  // Push user key from authors to current book item by book id
}
```

**Loop result:**

```
{
  id:1,
  name:"John Doe"
}

error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined
```

In this loop first time user found but second time return error.

How I can correctly (performancly) push book user by id in my case to `books` array items?

Result must be something like this:

```
var books = [
    {id: 1, title: "Javascript", user: {id: 1, name: "John Doe"}},
    {id: 2, title: "PHP"},
    {id: 3, title: "Dart", user: {id: 4, name: "Alex Rio"}},
    {id: 4, title: "C++", user: {id: 42, name: "Paul Radmond"}}
]
```

Comment: There is a similar question and a nice accepted answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/q/68258096/14032355

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are too close. Just check if the author is found or not. If found then add the user object to the book object. Follow this-

```js
const books = [
  {id: 1, title: "Javascript"},
  {id: 2, title: "PHP"},
  {id: 3, title: "Dart"},
  {id: 4, title: "C++"}
];
const authors = [
  {book_id: 1, user: {id: 1, name: "John Doe"}},
  {book_id: 3, user: {id: 4, name: "Alex Rio"}},
  {book_id: 4, user: {id: 42, name: "Paul Radmond"}}
];

const result = books.map(book => {
  const author = authors.find(author => author.book_id === book.id);
  
  if (author) {
    book.user = author.user;
  }
  
  return book
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in this way

```
const result = books.map(book => {
  const author = authors.find(author => author.book_id === book.id)
  if(author) return {...book, user: author}
  return book;
})
```